# Connecting to HBase through Spark Phoenix Connector

Tags: apache-spark, hbase, apache-phoenix

I am trying to load a HBase Table through spark sql connector.
I am able to get the schema of the table

```
 val port = s"${configuration.get(ZOOKEEPER_CLIENT_PORT, "2181")}"
 val znode = s"${configuration.get(ZOOKEEPER_ZNODE_PARENT, "/hbase")}"
 val zkUrl = s"${configuration.get(ZOOKEEPER_QUORUM, "localhost")}"
 val url = s"jdbc:phoenix:$zkUrl:$port:$znode"
 val props = new Properties()
 val table ="SOME_Metrics_Test"
 props.put("driver", "org.apache.phoenix.jdbc.PhoenixDriver")
 val df = spark.read.jdbc(url, getEscapedFullTableName(table), props)
```

If I do df.printSchema I can fetch the schema of the table

```
scala> df.printSchema
root
 |-- PK: string (nullable = false)
 |-- status: string (nullable = true)
 |-- other_Status: string (nullable = true)
```

But when I do `df.show` I am getting this error :

```
org.apache.phoenix.schema.TableNotFoundException: ERROR 1012 (42M03): Table undefined. tableName=SOME_Metrics_Test
  at org.apache.phoenix.query.ConnectionQueryServicesImpl.getAllTableRegions(ConnectionQueryServicesImpl.java:542)
  at org.apache.phoenix.iterate.BaseResultIterators.getParallelScans(BaseResultIterators.java:480)
```

Any idea why this error is coming and what can I do to resolve it?
While starting the spark shell I have added `phoenix-4.7.0-HBase-1.1-client-spark.jar` and `hbase-site.xml` in the spark-shell command.

Answer (score 1):

Try this,

```
val phoenixDF = spark.read.format("org.apache.phoenix.spark")
      .option("table", "my_table") 
      .option("zkUrl", "0.0.0.0:2181") 
      .load()
```